# How to insert an InputStream in to a CLOB using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jetty

I am writing a method that receives a Comma Separated text file as a InputStream through a web service.  I created my table using the following SQL script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE FILE_NUMBER_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
MINVALUE 1
NOMAXVALUE;

CREATE TABLE FILES
(
    ID        NUMBER  NOT NULL ,
    FILE      CLOB NOT NULL
);
```

In my unit test I am using the following code to generate the CSV.  I cannot create a file b/c of admin rights on the machine the test may be running on:

```
    String simulatedCSVFile = new String("col1,col2\\ndata1,data2");
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                simulatedCSVFile.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

My method currently looks like this:

```
public void uploadCSVFile(InputStream stream) {
    try {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;

        conn = db.getDataSource().getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO FILES(ID,FILE) VALUES(FILE_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?)";
        preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStmt.setAsciiStream(1, stream);
        int count = preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

When I execute the method to test it I get an exception that reads "Message payload is of type: jetty.HttpParser" when setAsciiStream is called.

Any idea how I can convert the stream so that it can be added to the SQL for the CLOB?

Comment: I've never heard of sending InputStreams through web services. Why don't you send byte array instead?

Comment: I could, but I don't want to back-track since the service is working.  The Inputstream has the data because I can see it when I debug the it.  The issue is getting the data from the InputStream in to the PreparedStatement.

Comment: I managed to get it to 'work' by converting the InputStream in to a String and then executing "preparedStmt.setString(1, theString);" instead of "setAsciiStream".  I am still not sure if this technique is the 'best/standard' way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: That exception appears to be coming from your JDBC driver. Which driver(/connection pool) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `InputStreamReader` and `setCharacterStream` method of `PreparedStatement` ?